# How to load a javascript function in html (span tag)

Tags: javascript, html, onload-event

Here I have an HTML Element:

```
<h3>Current Date: <span id="spanDate"></span></h3>
```

How am I able to (on)load the function below between the span tag

```
function aDate()
{
var d=new Date();
var weekday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var monthname=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
document.write(weekday[d.getDay()] + " ");
document.write(d.getDate() + ". ");
document.write(monthname[d.getMonth()] + " ");
document.write(d.getFullYear());
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/QBsWy/

Comment: @PSL - Inline JavaScript? Ew.

Comment: @j08691 :D..... He is using document.write... :) Try this way, http://jsfiddle.net/9Bnkc/

Comment: You should write var weekday= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday",....] and you can find out on Google why not use new Array() to declare arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var monthname = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    // Set your output to a variable
    var output = weekday[d.getDay()] + " " + d.getDate() + ". " + monthname[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();

    // Target the ID of the span and update the HTML
    document.getElementById('spanDate').innerHTML = output;
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QBsWy/8/